# What and where is my bootloader on a linode instance?

Tags: linode, arch-linux, boot-loader

Using a virtualized instance on linode.com, I don't see where my bootloader is.

In the usual place where I would find `grub`, i.e. in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`, I don't see any files or directories below the `/boot` path. It's completely empty.

How do I find out where my bootloader is for my server instance on linode.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boot loader is the code executed immediately after booting the system; part of it resides in the MBR (sector 1, cylinder 1 of the boot disk), but that is only 512 bytes in size so it usually chainloads a bigger bootloader elsewhere.

If you don't have a /boot/grub (and the bootloader stages required to boot with grub), then you're not using grub.

See if `/etc/lilo.conf` exists, instead.

`man lilo`

Comment: nope. no `lilo` either. Linode.com uses Xen virtualization so it does not use any bootloader like `lilo` or `grub`.

The issue I am really trying to solve is to start up `systemd` after my linode instance is rebooted.